# Combining previous array values in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have directories in an array, and my goal is to get both the folder name and the folder's path in a foreach (or equivalent) statement.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<?
$array = array("folder","path","here");
foreach ($array as $value){
    echo "File Name: $value";
    echo "File Path:       ";
}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to get the path. What I'm going for, is something like this.

```
File Name: folder
File Path: /folder

File Name: path
File Path: /folder/path

File Name: here
File Path: /folder/path/here
```

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: `echo implode( '/', $array);` will give you the final full path.

Comment: I see that, but what about getting the path of the second folder (for example)? An implode would include the third folder too, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the path within the loop:

```
<?
$array = array("folder","path","here");
$path = "";
foreach ($array as $value){
    $path .= "/$value";
    echo "File Name: $value";
    echo "File Path: $path";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For your exact output, you can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
foreach ($array as $current_index => $value){
    echo "File Name: $value";
    echo "File Path: /" . implode( '/', array_slice( $array, 0, $current_index + 1));
}
```

This [will output](http://viper-7.com/oMWXSI):

```
File Name: folder
File Path: /folder

File Name: path
File Path: /folder/path

File Name: here
File Path: /folder/path/here
```

Otherwise, for just the full path, you can just use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
echo implode( '/', $array);
```

Comment: shouldn't that be -1 as opposed to +1 in the array slice?

Comment: @dsol828 - It should not. (`array_slice()`'s third parameter is a count of the number of elements to take, see the demo)

Comment: that's odd. I just tried your code and it returned every path as the full "/folder/path/here" - but changing it to a -1 seems to do the trick.

Comment: @dsol Really??? That's extremely odd, especially since I don't see anything in the documentation that would lead to such drastic output differences between PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `implode` function to combine elements of an array:

```
implode( '/', $array )
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php